# Install MariaDB and MySQL in CentOS 6 32bit in same server

Tags: mysql, installation, mariadb

I'm trying to install MariaDB with MySQL in the same server but got this errors:

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-client.i686 0:5.5.32-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-common for package: MariaDB-client-5.5.32-1.i686
---> Package MariaDB-server.i686 0:5.5.32-1 will be obsoleting
---> Package mysql-server.i686 0:5.5.33-1.el6.remi will be obsoleted
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-common.i686 0:5.5.32-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-compat for package: MariaDB-common-5.5.32-1.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-compat.i686 0:5.5.32-1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: mysql-5.5.33-1.el6.remi.i686 conflicts MySQL
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mysql conflicts with MariaDB-server-5.5.32-1.i686
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I read docs [here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/) and [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-with-yum/) but that doesn't help since those guides are for alone installation I though, how I can install MariaDB and MySQL both in the same server by using `yum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB is a total drop-in replacement for MySQL - it even uses the same configuration files and folders.

If you're utterly sold on using both simultaneously, then you'd probably be best compiling from source and configuring all the folders manually. I am speaking from Debian derivative basis, so I may be off the mark regarding yum, but generally the package manager versions tend to be a simple replacement.

I would still run the following before taking the plunge, just in case something goes wrong:
`mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > alldbs.sql`. Then you can easily restore with `mysql -u root -p < alldbs.sql`.

Source: I recently attempted to do this myself, and found that there was no feature I used in MySQL that wasn't totally compatible with MariaDB.

Comment: Correct about MariaDB and correct that package managers typically will only support 1 installation of one or the other... but you missed an important point: there's no need to compile from source -- MySQL has "Linux-Generic" "Compressed TAR Archives" and MariaDB calls them "Gzipped Tar File" -- pre-compiled downloads for 32 and 64 bit linux  without the package manager nonsense.  Extract to the desired location and symlink to (or rename) the resulting directory to your desired `basedir`.  This is the only thing I ever use, whether I'm deploying one or more instances on a single machine.

Comment: Please try MySQL sandbox. https://github.com/datacharmer/mysql-sandbox